# Indices of smallest n values over whole Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, minimum, indices

I'm searching for an efficient way to extract the indices of the n smallest values over the whole data frame.

For example, given the following df with n = 2:

```
    colA    colB    colC
r1   33      75      22
r2    1      52      95
r3   71       7      68
```

I would like to get, in some form, the indices [(r2, colA), (r3, colB)] corresponding to the 2 smallest values over the whole df: 1 and 7.

The order between the indices is not important (The corresponding values may not be sorted).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Neo's answer, in the meanwhile, I found the following solution:

```
n=2
list(df.stack().sort_values().head(n).index)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**nsmallest** -

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"colA":[33,1,71],"colB":[75,52,7],"colC":[22,95,68]})

df.apply(pd.Series.nsmallest, axis=1, n=1)

df.apply(pd.Series.nsmallest, axis=1, n=2)
```

[image: nsmallest example]

Comment: Is there a similar solution that takes into account the whole df, and not each col (/row) separately?

Comment: Sure @MatanSolomon  The min value for each numerical column in the dataframe run 'df.min(numeric_only=True)'

Comment: For the minimum value in the entire dataframe run 'df.min(numeric_only=True).min()'

Comment: What you did there is taking the minimum over the columns' minima, which might be different if I need the n=2 (for example) smallest values. For example, if colA = [33,21,71], and colB=[75,9,7], the minimum is indeed 7 and can be extracted as you mentioned, but the 2 smallest values are 7,9, when 9 will not be taken into account. Do I get it right?

Comment: Is there a way to place NaN on the non-minimum cells, as you did there, but w.r.t to entire df?

Answer (score 0):

**df.min**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"colA":[33,1,71],"colB":[75,52,7],"colC":[22,95,68]})

#The min value for each numerical column in the dataframe
df.min(numeric_only=True)

#The minimum value in the entire dataframe
df.min(numeric_only=True).min()
```

[image: df.min example]